# How can I remove a hidden link at the bottom of my WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, links

I recently downloaded a WP Theme and started building a page. However, if I scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page, I notice a hidden link for an adult toy store. I have searched all of the theme files with TextMate and there is no mention of that specific link in any of the files.

My guess is that someone edited the WP theme in an attempt to do some black hat link-building.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That theme is from some collection posted on a Blogspot site. Read this:
[Why You Should Never Search For Free WordPress Themes in Google or Anywhere Else](http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/)

There's a pretty good chance nobody edited anything, and the link was there in the first place. If, for whatever reason, you're set on continuing to use that particular theme, the Authenticity Checker and Exploit Scanner tools linked early on in the article might find the code responsible for the link.

Answer (score 1):

look for base64 encoding in your theme

http://techpp.com/2008/11/29/how-to-decode-encoded-php-script-in-wordpress-themes/